# How to allow R to ignore parameters of my function, without it skipping to next parameter?

Tags: r, function, gwr

I have this function

```
GWR.function <- function(shape1,shape2,shape3,x,y,...)
```

there are 3 shapefiles, I want R to allow shape2 and shape3 to be missing.

Although for example if I use a  if(missing(shape2)) {}
and then input:

```
GWR.function(NY.council.data,Borough.Areas,'PERCENT.WHITE.NON.HISPANIC',
     'PERCENT.NRECEIVES.PUBLIC.ASSISTANCE','PERCENT.FEMALE','PERCENT.MALE')
```

R will not recognise that there is only 2 shapefiles and that the second one is missing.

Comment: Pass the shapes parameters as a single list of shapes and then process the list dependent on its length.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters by name; if the names don't match `shape2` or `shape3`, those won't be passed.  For example,

```
 GWR.function(shape1 = NY.council.data, x = Borough.Areas, 
              y = 'PERCENT.WHITE.NON.HISPANIC', 
              a = 'PERCENT.NRECEIVES.PUBLIC.ASSISTANCE',
              b = 'PERCENT.FEMALE',
              c = 'PERCENT.MALE')
```

Alternatively, if you want to specify them by position, just don't put anything in those positions, e.g.

```
GWR.function(NY.council.data, , , # The two previous params are missing
             Borough.Areas, 'PERCENT.WHITE.NON.HISPANIC', 
             'PERCENT.NRECEIVES.PUBLIC.ASSISTANCE', 'PERCENT.FEMALE', 'PERCENT.MALE')
```